# Horizontal scrollview within vertical scrollview not allowing image stretch

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, iphone-x

I have set up a horizontal scrollview within a vertical scrollview. The horizontal scrollview needs to contain a dynamic number of image views in a gallery style format. When the user drags the vertical scroll view down I want it to stretch the image currently in view, maintaining the aspect ratio to give a stretchy header type effect.

Without the horizontal scrollview and just a container for the image views it works. However when I introduce the horizontal scrollview the main view controller seems to show above the image rather than it being pinned and stretched. I've tried setting contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to never on the scrollview but it doesn't work.

Here is the where the image view is added to the content view:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let imageViewOne = UIImageView()

   imageViewOne.image = UIImage(named: "profile-image")!
   imageViewContainerView.addSubview(imageViewOne)
   imageViewOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   imageViewOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
   imageViewOne.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
   imageViewOne.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewContainerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
   imageViewOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
   imageViewOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
 }
```

This is without the scrollview when stretched/pulled down and it works
[image]

This is with the scrollview when stretched/pulled down and it doesn't work - you can see it shows the main view behind rather than the image I've pinned to the main view top. I suspect it's something to do with the content inset for scroll views in iOS 11.

[image]

Here is the storyboard setup:
[image]

The second content view is the "imageViewContainerView" in the code.

How can achieve what I want - to pin and stretch the image as shown in the first picture but inside a horizontal scroll view?

Comment: This to me looks like mis-interaction between the two different gesture recognizers for the two different scrollviews. Could you share what you're doing to stretch the image (without the horizontal scroll view), and how you're handling the scroll behavior (scrollViewDidScroll, something else?). My guess is that you need to properly delegate the vertical scrolls to the vertical scroll view, while maintaining the horizontal gestures going to the horizontal scroll view -- I imagine they are all going to the "top" horizontal scroll view right now.

Comment: Without the horizontal scroll view its all in the storyboard - the image view is pinned to an exact same placeholder view within the vertical scroll view apart from the top constraint which is pinned to the controller views top. This means the image grows as the vertical scroll is pulled down as the bottom constraint is pinned to the placeholder bottom within the vertical scroll view. With the horizontal scroll view this still happens I just can’t see the top of the image. I probably need to do this in a different way, tried with frames but there are issues with the content offset on iOS 11

Comment: Is your horizontal scroll view the outer one, or the vertical one? I think you need the vertical scroll view to be the inner most one, but perhaps that's what you already have? Does the white overlay that's happening stretch as you vertically stretch the image, alongside the image stretching?

Comment: I've been attempting this approach and can get it almost working in a number of ways but there's always a slight issue with something in the approach. I will post the answer when I get it.